# Pushwoosh Show Past Notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, pushwoosh

I use Push Notifications from Pushwoosh.com.  In their tutorials, they have many guides, but nothing that I could find for a view that allows you to view past notifications the device has received.  As many people can tend to dismiss or clear notifications quickly, it is usually a good idea for them to go back and view them within the app itself.  Does anyone know if this is possible using Pushwoosh?

Comment: What platform are you talking about? This is possible on Android, but not on iOS at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do some of your own work here. It's not that difficult either.

When a push notification is received, you could save its information to `NSUserDefaults` or to your own database and then retrieve this when you need it.